# Difference between set and add methods in list in java

Tags: java, list, dynamic, set, addition

So I was asked in a question to generate Pascal triangle using 2D List in java.... I was able to find out the solution but... **when I was using the add method() in my program I was not getting any error but when I used the set method I was getting an error of ArrayOutOfBoundIndex for length 1**. Can somebody help me in pointing out the difference.(The line where error was coming has been commented)

Input- numRows = 5
Expected Output- [[1],[1,1],[1,2,1],[1,3,3,1],[1,4,6,4,1]]

```
    public List<List<Integer>> generate(int numRows) {
            List<List<Integer>> Pa = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
            List<Integer>row,prev = null;
            
            for(int i = 0 ; i< numRows;i++){
                row=new ArrayList<Integer>();
                for(int j = 0 ; j<=i;j++){
                    if(j==i||j==0)
                        row.add(1);
                    else{
                      // thisLine -->
                        row.set(j,prev.get(j-1)+prev.get(j));
                    }
                    
                }
                prev=row;
                Pa.add(i,row);
            }
            return Pa;
        }
```

```
  at line 64, java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBounds
  at line 70, java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBoundsCheckIndex
  at line 248, java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.checkIndex
  at line 373, java.base/java.util.Objects.checkIndex
  at line 439, java.base/java.util.ArrayList.set
  at line 12, Solution.generate
  at line 54, __DriverSolution__.__helper__
  at line 84, __Driver__.main
```

Comment: The `set()` method can only overwrite elements at existing indices. The `add()` method adds new elements.

Comment: `set` is used for replacement of *already existing* value in list at specified index. `add` adds new element at the end of list, or at specified index (previous element at that index will not be replaced but shifted right).

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is, you are trying to set a value in a non-existing index.

To understand the case you should know the basic difference:

**set() Parameters**

The set() method takes two parameters.

- index - position of the element to be replaced
- element - new element that is to be stored at index

**set() Return Values**

- returns the element previously present at index
- throws IndexOutOfBoundsException, if index is out of range

**ArrayList set() Vs. add()**

The syntax of the add() and set() method looks quite similar.

```
// syntax of add()
arraylist.add(int index, E element)

// syntax of set()
arraylist.set(int index, E element)
```

And, both the methods are adding a new element to the arraylist. This is why some people consider both methods similar.

However, there is a major difference between them.

- The set() method adds a new element at the specified position by replacing the older element at that position.
- The add() method adds a new element at the specified position by shifting the older element towards the right position.

Example:

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

list.add("a");
list.add(1, "b");
System.out.println(list);

list.set(0, "c");
System.out.println(list);

list.add(0, "d");
System.out.println(list);
---------------Output -------------------------------------
[a, b]

[c, b]

[d, c, b]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is setting value by non-existting index. Let's suppose you have numRows = 4

So:

when i == 2:

j == 0 -> creating element with Index = 0

j == 1 - > trying to set new element for Index = 1. (There is no element with id = 1, when you have only one element with id = 0)